# Importance of Double Helix DNA Structure

Tags: dna, proteins

Gene expression involves transcribing only one strand of DNA molecule. So i was wondering what are some biological advantages of the double stranded DNA?

Comment: It maintains a certain structure - and it also holds a second copy of a strand (though reverse complement). This can be used to repair damages.

Comment: @Chris — Please make the point about DNA repair into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The structure allows for the DNA to be tightly packed into chromosomes. It also provides an extremely stable backbone with the negatively charged phosphates pointing to the outside of the molecule. This charge aids in the attachment of other molecules to the strand of DNA.

DNA double helix allows it to be stable and it won't easily destroyed.

Comment: Unconvincing answer lacking critical comparison to support your points. You don't explain how dsDNA can be packed more tightly than ssDNA or how it is "more stable".

Answer (score 3):

The **most important** role of this peculiar double helix structure of DNA is to facilitate replication....in preparation of cell division each of the 2 strands acts as a template thus facilitating precise copying of genes....in the Nature(1953), Watson & Crick also suggested that " *[It has not escaped our notice that the specific pairing we have postulated immediately suggests a possible copying mechanism for the genetic material](http://www.nature.com/nature/dna50/watsoncrick.pdf)*"...

Also, the extremely stable structure doesn't allow DNA to mutate rapidly, unlike RNA...thus converting it into an "**efficient information storage structure**"....

& lastly this double helix structure is also **resistive against extreme physical changes**...as is evident from Griffith's experiment, where the heat-killed bacteria had their DNA intact...

Also try this link- "[*Genetic Implications of the Structure of Deoxyribonucleic Acid*](http://www.nature.com/nature/dna50/watsoncrick2.pdf)"- Watson & Crick....as it always helps to learn from the very masters of DNA structure;)

Comment: Your first point is valid, but only to a point. It is necessary that a dsDNA is formed at some point as the replicative form, but ssDNA viruses show that there is no need for a dsDNA genome for replication. Your second point is nonsense. It is the phosphodiester bond between the deoxyriboses that is more stable than that between ribososes and the lack of proof-reading that is the difference in mutability. And the third point likewise is nonsense. You don't show the heat resistance is due to the double strandedness. And your final reference is dead.